# How can one manually add a line to the pdflatex -recorder .fls file?

Tags: pdftex, luatex, latexmk

I'm using a LuaLaTeX package that includes a feature that calls an external executable (i.e. something that requires `-shell-escape`) to generate a TeX file from a distinct source file, which is then `\input` into the main file. 
For example, I put `\specialinclude{file.a}` in `main.tex`, which calls an external executable to convert `file.a` into `file.tex` and then expands to `\input{file.tex}`.

I'd like latexmk to be able to pick up the dependency on `file.a` so that it knows to rebuild `main.pdf` if `file.a` changes, even though the actually included file, `file.tex`, hasn't changed. I'm using `latexmk`/`lualatex` with the `-recorder` option, which successfully picks up on the use of `file.tex` but not `file.a`. Is there a way to manually tell the `recorder` option that a file has been input? This would result in a line like `INPUT file.a` in the `main.fls` file. I'm thinking something along the lines of `\recorder{file.a}` right before the call to `\specialinclude{file.a}`.

Comment: The calls made by the shell-escape are recorded in the `.log` file with the keyword `runsystem`. I don't think there's user's access to the `.fls` file.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here are three solutions:

1. Since `latexmk` also examines the `.log` file for dependencies, you can persuade `latexmk` that there is a dependency on `file.a` by writing a suitable line to the `.log` file.  The following definition of `\recorder` does this:

   ```
   \newcommand\recorder[1]{\typeout{(#1)}}
   ```
2. Get the filename into the `.fls` file by opening the file without reading it:

   ```
   \newread\tmpread
   \newcommand\recorder[1]{%
       \openin\tmpread=#1
       \closein\tmpread
   }
   ```
3. Instead of having your document do the processing of `file.a`, define a custom dependency to generate `file.tex` from `file.a`.  This avoids the use of `-shell-escape`, and has the advantage of only invoking the external program when `file.a` has changed.

Which solution is best for your case depends on details of the situation, e.g., what the LuaLaTex package does beyond simply calling the external program.

Comment: I was doing #3, but #1 works even better. Thanks!